# OnSubscriptionError : ServiceResponseException: Unable to retrieve events for this subscription

Tags: exchangewebservices

Using C# .NET 4.6.1 with Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices nuget package 2.2.0 connecting to Office 365.

Expected disconnection is set to every 3 minutes.

Error is handled as below:

1. The OnSubscriptionError event fires with a ServiceResponseException.
   "Unable to retrieve events for this subscription.  The subscription must be recreated., The events couldn't be read."
2. I recreate/renew the subscription as suggested by the error.
3. I then receive one notification but no more.
4. I have to restart the C# program/service in order to get StreamingSubscriptions working again.

What is the best practice for recreating/renewing the subscription?

Do you know of any other possible causes? - Microsoft themselves have been mainly focused on tweaking the throttling.

Thanks.

Comment: facing the same issue.. were you able to find a solution?

Comment: facing the same issue, any solution yet ?

Comment: facing same issue, any solution?